# Is it possible to exchange the content of two registers in a single clock pulse?

Tags: digital-logic, register

There are two register R1 and R2. How is it possible to exchange the content of R1 and R2 in a single clock pulse using Common bus architecture?

Comment: I don't know what "common bus architecture" is supposed to mean, but unless there is a instruction to exchange the contents of two registers, you probably can't do it in a single instruction cycle.

Comment: Are you designing your own Hardware in an FPGA or are you interfacing to a MCU?

Answer (score 5):

You can't.  CBA doesn't work that way.

Comment: I was studying Register transfer language from the book Morris Mano. It's clearly written there that it's possible(I have also studied this on a number of sites). See the following link http://www.slideshare.net/sanjeevpatel4x/register-transfer-language

Comment: @JatinKhurana  RTL is completely unrelated to CBA.  You can't look at one and infer the capabilities of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Exchanging registers in a single cycle is only possible if both registers can present themselves as input to the other register at the same time. Only a single register can emit to the bus at any time, therefore a minimum of 3 cycles would be required (store R1, move R2 to R1, load R2; or the XOR trick, which still requires 3 operations).

Comment: With some pipeline configurations, effective two-cycle operation may be possible: during the first cycle, something on the bus may be stored to some register while register A outputs.  During the second cycle, register B is output to the bus and loaded from it.  During the third cycle, A is loaded from the bus while something else is output to it.  Operations would be spread over three cycles, but the first and last could be shared with other operations.